# How can I add a class to Scala Set

Tags: scala, reflection

I would like to passing a parameter via String and construct a Set of class objects, like this:

```
def getTypes(value: String) : Set[Class[Base]] = {
  var set = Set[Class[Base]]()
  var input = value.split(",")
  if(input.contains("XXX"))
    set ++ Class[xxx]
  if(input.contains("YYY"))
    set ++ Class[yyy]
  if(input.contains("ZZZ"))
    set ++ Class[zzz]
  set
}
```

Then looping the set and use class.newInstance() to create the actual object to do something later. The able code can compile, but when it run, it complaint that

```
Error:(32, 16) object java.lang.Class is not a value
    set ++ Class[xxx]
```

Any clue about about that?

Comment: use classOf[xxx] instead Class[xxx]

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your snippet. One, as aravindKrishna pointed, is you're trying to get `Class` literals improperly.
The other one is, you're treating your *immutable* `Set` like you would a mutable one. Remember you can't mutate the object itself - every operation returns a new one - so you should either reassign the variable every time (and using `var`s is discouraged for functional code), or use recursion, or construct the entire set in one go.

Here's an example of how to construct the set in one go:

```
def getTypes(value: String): Set[Class[_ <: Base]] = {
  val mapping = Map(
    "XXX", classOf[xxx],
    "YYY", classOf[yyy],
    "ZZZ", classOf[zzz])

  val input = value.split(",").toSet

  mapping.collect {
    case (k, v) if input contains k => v
  }.toSet
}
```

Or, translating your original code snippet more literally,

```
def getTypes(value: String): Set[Class[_ <: Base]] = {
  val input = value.split(",").toSet

  Set[Class[_ <: Base]]() ++
    input.find("XXX" ==).map(_ => classOf[xxx]) ++
    input.find("YYY" ==).map(_ => classOf[yyy]) ++
    input.find("ZZZ" ==).map(_ => classOf[zzz])
}
```